# XSLT String custom modification/manipulation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml document that conatins references to other xml tags in the same document, however these references are not in xpath, but in a similar notation.
For example, rather than having

```
"/contains[0]/contains[1]/inputPorts[0]"
```

the reference is in this form

```
"//@contains.0/@contains.1/@inputPorts.0"
```

I need XSLT to understand the reference, so I would like to know if there is a way in XSLT to transform the non-xpath string to the actual xpath. Basically I would like to know if you can define these sort of string transformation rules in XSLT?

Rules like: for every substring between /, transform ".X" to "[X]", or 
for every / remove the first "@" after it and so on..

Comment: Do you have [`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) available? This would be the easiest solution. Coverting these strings to XPath expressions is possible, but using the results as queries is AFAIK impossible.

Comment: String transformations are possible - however, interpreting the resulting string as an XPath expression requires an evaluation function which is supported only by some processors.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this in 2 tranformations - one that would produce another XSLT, which would have the proper xpath expressions in the attributes and then running that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One would need to know the complete syntax and semantics of this local path language. Also, which version of XPath/XSLT you are using. In XSLT 3.0 you can do

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="replace($path, '@([a-z]+)\.([0-9]+)', '$1[$2]'"/>
```

Regular expressions need version 2.0, xsl:evaluate needs version 3.0 (but many XSLT processors have a proprietary equivalent).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot rely on the functionality of 3.0 (which is a shame, I know) but anything 2.0 should be ok. I am guessing then that a carefully written regular expression should do the trick, and then some workaround to dynamically use the returned string as xpath?

Comment: As I mentioned, many XSLT processors have some kind of dynamic xx:evaluate() function for evaluating a dynamically-constructed XPath expression.